# Get full year data in column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I have a case where Full Year total is loaded into the 13th month. I have to take the total per OpNum as columns. I have shown as-is and expected outcome below.

Full year data is simple sum of 12 months. I tried using group by and sum but it didn't work

```
df[FY] = df.groupby('OpNum','Year')['MTD'].sum()
```

ValueError: No axis named Year for object type DataFrame

AS-IS DF:

```
OpNum   Year    month   MTD
0   OP1 2021    1   1000
1   OP1 2021    2   1000
2   OP1 2021    3   1000
3   OP1 2021    4   1000
4   OP1 2021    5   1000
5   OP1 2021    6   1000
6   OP1 2021    7   1000
7   OP1 2021    8   1000
8   OP1 2021    9   1000
9   OP1 2021    10  1000
10  OP1 2021    11  1000
11  OP1 2021    12  1000
12  OP1 2021    13  12000
13  OP2 2021    1   2000
14  OP2 2021    2   2000
15  OP2 2021    3   2000
16  OP2 2021    4   2000
17  OP2 2021    5   2000
18  OP2 2021    6   2000
19  OP2 2021    7   2000
20  OP2 2021    8   2000
21  OP2 2021    9   2000
22  OP2 2021    10  2000
23  OP2 2021    11  2000
24  OP2 2021    12  2000
25  OP2 2021    13  24000
```

Expected output :

```
    OpNum   Year    month   MTD FY
0   OP1 2021    1   1000    12000
1   OP1 2021    2   1000    12000
2   OP1 2021    3   1000    12000
3   OP1 2021    4   1000    12000
4   OP1 2021    5   1000    12000
5   OP1 2021    6   1000    12000
6   OP1 2021    7   1000    12000
7   OP1 2021    8   1000    12000
8   OP1 2021    9   1000    12000
9   OP1 2021    10  1000    12000
10  OP1 2021    11  1000    12000
11  OP1 2021    12  1000    12000
12  OP2 2021    1   2000    24000
13  OP2 2021    2   2000    24000
14  OP2 2021    3   2000    24000
15  OP2 2021    4   2000    24000
16  OP2 2021    5   2000    24000
17  OP2 2021    6   2000    24000
18  OP2 2021    7   2000    24000
19  OP2 2021    8   2000    24000
20  OP2 2021    9   2000    24000
21  OP2 2021    10  2000    24000
22  OP2 2021    11  2000    24000
23  OP2 2021    12  2000    24000
```

Comment: correct your syntax and use `transform()`: `df.groupby(['OpNum','Year'])['MTD'].transform('sum')`

Comment: Your data doesn't quite make sense. Why do you have a month 13 in your in DF but not in the out?

Comment: Feels like Bureau of Labor Statistics data, which uses M13 as a 'whole-year average'; perhaps the easiest way is to just create two data frames, one with the months and one with the M13, then merge back the total value on year after renaming.

Comment: If `MTD` means 'month to date' you shouldn't be using `sum`.

Comment: @ifly6 agreed - needs `.cumsum` or some sort of rolling `sum`

Comment: Thanks transform() works perfectly, along with df.columns.str.strip() to avoid key errors.

Comment: Yes, the data is in little different form. They have MTD for months 1-12 and month 13 has sum of months 1-12. In case of using transform first I have to filter out the 13th month. 

As, output requires the total in columns.